# Let $f : U \subset \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable at $a \in U$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Prove that there are $\epsilon >0$ and $M>0$ such that 
$$|h|<\epsilon \implies |f(a+h)-f(a)|<M.|h|.$$

A hint is enough, thank you. Do you know when you know the answer, but can't write it out in words?

Comment: The problem doesn't make sense as stated. Please review and edit and get it exactly right.

Comment: Really? Why do you think that? I will remove the "excess" and tell me if you think it is better.

Comment: There's no excess. There is a deficit. For example, where is $a$ in the statement of the problem? And why do you think "$|h|<\epsilon \implies |f(y)-f(x)|<M|y-x|$ makes any sense? What is the relationship among $h,x,y?$

Comment: Oh, sure. You're right. Congratz. Now you can see that the hint below is helping?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Use (and proof) the fact that definition of differentiability can be written as:

There exist a function $\epsilon(h)$ and linear mapping (or matrix) $L$ such that

$$ f(x+h) - f(x) = L(h) + \epsilon(h) \| h \| $$

and $ |\epsilon(h)|$ goes to zero as $h$ goes to zero (what does this means in terms of open balls?). Now you can use common inequalities to prove the statement.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Using the $L(h)$ notation just reminded of the case $m=1$. Cheers. :)

Comment: I don't see how this is helpful.